# The vector space $\mathbb{Q}^\times/\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to understand why $\mathbb{Q}^\times/\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}=\{\pm1\}\times(A/2A)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with basis given by elements $\ell+\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}$, where $\ell$ is prime together with $-1+\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}$, and where A is a free abelian group with a basis consisting of the set of prime numbers. We define $\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}:=\{f^2:f\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

The first piece of information I am trying to grapple with is that $\mathbb{Q}^\times=\{\pm1\}\times A$. Why is this true? If $A$ is a free abelian group with basis the set of primes, wouldn't this free group just give us a subset of the integers? And then why do we get the above equality?

How is this a vector space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic Note that, as a group, it allows negative exponents, hence not always integers.

Comment: If A is a free group with basis the set of prime numbers, can't we only add $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of primes to get elements of $A$?

Comment: The point is what does "$\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of primes" mean here. The group structure here is multiplication, so for example the subgroup generated by a prime $p$ is in fact the set $\{p^k: k \in \mathbb Z\}$, or in other words, $\{\dotsc, p^{-2}, p^{-1}, 1, p, p^2, \dotsc\}$.

Comment: Are elements of $2A$ then of the form $2p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}...$ or are the exponents all even?

Comment: @ponchan the exponents are all even. Part of what's confusing is that on the right hand side of the group isomorphism you have $\pm 1$ which is written multiplicatively crossed with $A/2A$ which is additive notation. Maybe it would be easier to think about if you wrote it as $A/A^2$.

Comment: @hunter And if we are thinking of this as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ shouldn't we be thinking of it additively as well?

Comment: You may think of it any way you want, but the law of composition is multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the unique prime factorization in $\mathbf Z$, every $x\in \mathbf Q^*$ can be written uniquely as a finite product $x=\pm \prod {p_i}^{a_i}$, where $a_i \in \mathbf Z$ and the $p_i$ are (positive) primes. This can also read $x= y^2\pm \prod {p_i}^{\alpha_i}$, with $\alpha_i=0,1$. It follows that every class $[x]$ mod $\mathbf {\mathbf Q^*}^{2}$ can be written uniquely $[x]=\pm \prod [{p_i}]^{\alpha_i}$ in the multiplicative abelian group $\mathbf Q^*/\mathbf {\mathbf Q^*}^{2}$. But the multiplicative law in this group can be denoted in an arbitrary way, for instance additively, so that $[x]=\pm \sum {\alpha_i}[{p_i}]$, where $\pm 1$ and ${\alpha_i}$ belong to the field $\mathbf F_2=\mathbf Z/2$. This shows that $\mathbf Q^*/\mathbf {\mathbf Q^*}^{2}$ is a vector space over $\mathbf F_2$, isomorphic to $\mathbf F_2 \times V$, where $V$ is the $\mathbf F_2$ - vector space on the basis {$[p_i]$}. This is clearly equivalent to your conclusion.